# Using RxSwift with Tableview containing texfields dismisses keyboard on dataSource update

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, tableview, rx-swift

I have a tableview containing forms so there are collection of textfields.
I am using RxSwift to bind data with tableview. When i try update dataSource with entered data in textfield, the whole tableview reloads and where the problem lies is instead of going on to next textfield, the keyboard dismisses.

Any suggestions would be of great help.
Here's a sample code

```
struct TableData {
  var name, value: String?
}

class TableRxViewController: UIViewController {

 var data: [TableData] = []
 let dataSource = BehaviorRelay<[TableData]>(value: [])
 var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RegisterCell", bundle: nil), 
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "RegisterCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addTableData()
    self.dataSource.accept(self.data)
    self.rxTableView()
}

func addTableData() {
    data.append(TableData(name: "first", value: ""))
    data.append(TableData(name: "second", value: ""))
    data.append(TableData(name: "third", value: ""))
    data.append(TableData(name: "fourth", value: ""))
    data.append(TableData(name: "fifth", value: ""))
}



func rxTableView() {
    self.dataSource.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) {
            (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: TableData) in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
            "RegisterCell") as! RegisterCell
            cell.loadCell(data: element)
            cell.textfield.rx
                .controlEvent([.editingDidEndOnExit, .editingDidEnd])
                .subscribe({ text in
                    var data = self.dataSource.value
                    data[index].value = cell.textfield.text ?? ""
                    self.dataSource.accept(data)
                })
                .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)

            return cell
        }
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of dataSource?

Comment: observable array of string.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. Observable<[String]>? has no member 'value'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too happy with this answer, but it's the best I have come up with so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textFields = [UITextField(), UITextField(), UITextField(), UITextField(), UITextField()]

    Observable.just(textFields).bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "MyCell")) { _, textField, cell in
        textField.frame = cell.contentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 8, dy: 8) // size properly
        cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
    }
    .disposed(by: bag)

    for fields in zip(textFields, textFields[1...]) {
        fields.0.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEndOnExit)
            .subscribe(onNext: { fields.1.becomeFirstResponder() })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    textFields.last!.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEndOnExit)
        .map { textFields.map { $0.text ?? "" }}
        .subscribe(onNext: {
            print("input finished with values:", $0)
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)
}
```

It's an interesting problem and I'm going to think about it for a bit.

Comment: i have used BehaviorRelay
let dataSource = BehaviorRelay<[String]>(value: [])

Comment: Okay, so presumably this `CommonTextField` has a value parameter?

Comment: let me update the code to make it more readable. Sorry for limited input at first.

Comment: I updated my answer, but I'm going to continue thinking about it.

Comment: I have updated my code. I will look into yours and see how it works. Thank you for your time and for looking into it :)